# How to extend namespaces with EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, ember.js

I've been programming in Javascript for a while. Recently I made quite a huge jQuery project and applied the Module Pattern as described in this wonderful article: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

This all went fine and dandy and the code looks slick and manageable, but I felt it could be better. I've spend the day looking for some Javascript frameworks, mostly ones that:

- Have UI binding support
- Have a templating system
- Can work with jQuery
- Help me organize my code in a similar way as I did with the module pattern

I've stumbled across frameworks like AngularJS, KnockOutJS, SpineJS, JavascriptMVC, etc. The one that really sticked out - and was quite praised - was EmberJS.

I decided to give it a shot, but it has not been easy. The availability of tutorials for EmberJS is very limited. After trying for a long time I managed to get some stuff running and I like what EmberJS does! There is only one thing I can't seem to figure out - which is also my question: **How can I extend an Ember namespace (made with Ember.Application.create)?**

**For clarification:** The old version of my project had a Core-namespace and a Util-namespace. Both contained their respective functions which all other classes could use. How can I have a Core- and Util-namespace with functions on top of the initial-namespace?

Do I just do:

```
MyNamespace = Ember.Application.create();
MyNamespace.Core = Ember.Application.create();
MyNamespace.Util = Ember.Application.create();
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't nest `Ember.Namespace`'s (where `Ember.Application` being a subclass of `Ember.Namespace`), see issue [#683](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/683).

Tome Dale, one of the core contributors, added an interesting answer about the layout of complex applications, see the [comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/683#issuecomment-5122333).

So you can either just use `App = Ember.Application.create()` and create your controllers, views, etc under this namespace. Or you can - if you intend to reuse some code in other projects/applications - split the namespace's like this:

```js
Util = Ember.Namespace.create({
    importantNames: 'Einstein'.w()
});

Core = Ember.Namespace.create({
    sqrt: function(x) { return Math.sqrt(x); }
});

App = Ember.Application.create();

...

App.myListController = Ember.Object.create({
    importantNamesBinding: 'Core.importantNames',
    sqrtBinding: 'Util.sqrt'
});
```

An `Ember.Application` extends `Ember.Namespace`, and adds functionality about handling events (click, ...). This stuff is useful when you write an application with views - in your `Core` and `Util` namespace you wouldn't need that stuff, that's why this is *just* an `Ember.Namespace`.

Comment: At first, thank you for your swift reply, very detailed. Second, I don't really mind non-nested namespaces, I was merely looking for the right function call to create a namespace-like object, which Ember.Namespace.Create is! If anything, I could have gone with my Module Pattern approach to have the namespaces (be it nested or not) on top of an Ember application, but that's just dirty.

Comment: After just trying it out, I found out nesting namespaces actually does work. Maybe it has changed in a recent version due to popular demand?