# How should I structure multiple instances of the same Ember.Application sub-class on the same page?

Tags: ember.js

I have a reasonably large Ember.Application ("MyApp"). I wrote it as a standalone ember-controlled page, but now I want to instantiate N-instances of the application hosted inside  an existing (non-ember) page.

Ember docs on Ember.Application suggest that the app should be both the class namespace AND the root of a singleton-instance, but in this case, I need one class namespace, and multiple instances. I don't want to load the classes separately per instance, they are actually fairly large and mobile is a major use-case.

Currently I have:

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create({ /* app state */); // namespace & instance
MyApp.SomeSupportingClass1 = ...
```

My impulse is to do:

```
MyApp = Ember.Object.create(); // namespace
MyApp.MyApp = Ember.Application.extend({ /* app state */ }); // instance class
MyApp.myAppInstances = Ember.ArrayController.create(); // instances of MyApp.MyApp
MyApp.SomeSupportingClass1 = ...
```

Will this cause problems? Is there a more 'ember-y' way to structure this?

Comment: I was asking myself the same question and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271546/how-to-extend-namespaces-with-emberjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I believe your only option is "[Ember Islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands)".

However, Godfrey the newest addition to Tilde, inc (Where Tom and Yehuda work), has been doing some work on FastBoot which will include "[Application Instances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-LZjy5QS7Q)". Once Godfrey's work lands in Ember you will have an official ember way of accomplishing this.

Update: It's also worth taking a look at [Ember Engines] as a way to bring multiple applications together.(http://ember-engines.com/)